# C: Accessing pointer to pointer to struct element from pointer to structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, operators, pointer-to-pointer

I want to access members of a struct from double pointer but I get the error

> "error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token"

- [C Double Pointer to Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638612/c-double-pointer-to-structure)
- [double pointer to struct inside struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18553181/double-pointer-to-struct-inside-struct)

:

```
struct test{
  struct foo **val;
};

struct foo{
  int a;
}

int main (){
  struct test *ptr = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(struct test));
  ptr->val = &foo;
  /*foo is already malloced and populated*/
  printf ("Value of a is %d", ptr->(*val)->a);
}
```

I've also tried:

```
*ptr.(**foo).a
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `(*(ptr->val))->a`?

Comment: `struct foo` is a *type*. It has no address.

Comment: @AlexD Aweseome, the error is gone but the value is shown to be "null". I have a struct foo which is malloced and whose element "a" is assigned some value inside an external function. To keep this value I assign a pointer ptr->val = &foo.

But when I try to print this value it shows null.

Comment: @user2816078 see my new answer! Is that what you seek for?

Comment: Among other things, you're missing a semicolon on the declaration of `struct foo`.

Comment: `&foo` is an error

Comment: @M.M do you think this is clear enough in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test {
    struct foo **val;
};

struct foo {
    int a;
};

int main(void) {
    struct test* test_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    struct foo* foo_ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
    foo_ptr->a = 5;    // equivalent to (*foo_ptr).a = 5;
    test_ptr->val = &foo_ptr;
    printf ("Value of a is %d\n", (*(test_ptr->val))->a);
    free(test_ptr);
    free(foo_ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
Value of a is 5
```

In my example:

1. I allocate dynamically space for a `struct test`.
2. I allocate dynamically space for a `struct foo`.
3. I assign the value 5 to the member `a` of `foo_ptr`.
4. I assign the address of the allocated object of `struct foo` to the
   member `val` of `test_ptr`.
5. I print member `a` the struct that the double pointer `val` points
   to.

---

Note, in your example: `struct foo` is a **type**, so it doesn't make sense to ask for its address.

Also, you were missing a semicolon when you were done with the declaration of `struct foo`.

Oh, and make sure [not to cast the return value of malloc()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score -2):

in `ptr->val = &foo;`, foo is a struct (you declared it in lines 5 to 7). Taking its address does not give a `**`, but only a `*`.

Also it seems multiple things have the same names; is a `foo` the *name* of a structure or an instance of it, or both?

Then, when you dereference it: `ptr->(*val)->a` does seem the wrong sequence.
as `ptr->val` is the address of `foo` (that's what you assigned in the line above it), what would `ptr->(*val)` be??

I think `ptr->val.a` would give you your `a`. But still, the `val` is declared as a `**` and consistently used as a `*`. It might work, but makes not much sense.

Comment: `foo` and `struct foo` are unrelated (struct tags have a separate "namespace" to other names).  But even if they were the same thing, you can't take the address of a type

Comment: That was my point. Surely, you can name all your things the same name and trust the compiler to keep it sorted out. But it is not helping maintainability and human understanding of the code. It would be better to give it different names, even if not required.